# Unit testing AWS Lambda that uses Layers - Node JS app

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, npm, mocha.js, aws-sam

I have a SAM application with a bunch of Lambda functions and layers, using Mocha/Chai to run unit tests on the individual functions.

The issue is, that I am also using Layers for shared local modules.

The SAM project structure is like this..

functions/

- function-one/

  - app.js
  - package.json
- function-two/

  - app.js
  - package.json

layers/

- layer-one/

  - moduleA.js
  - moduleB.js
  - package.json
- layer-two/

  - moduleC.js
  - package.json

According to AWS once the function and layers are deployed, to `require` a local layer from a function you use this path...

`const moduleA = require('/opt/nodejs/moduleA');`

However, that running locally as a unit test wont resolve to anything.

Any idea on how to resolve the paths to the  layer modules when running unit tests?

I could set an ENV var, and then set a base path for the layers based on that, but I was wondering if there was a more elegant solution I was missing...

Is there any way to alias the paths when running Mocha ?

other options are to use `SAM INVOKE` but that has massive overheads and is more integration testing...

Comment: Can you add the code of your `function-one/package.json` ... what I've done in the past is in the `dependencies` section add something like `"moduleA": "file:../packages/layer/moduleA"` then in your code just a require without path: `const moduleA = require("moduleA")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I swapped over to using Jest which does support module mappings

In the package.json...

```
... 
"scripts": {
   "test": "jest"
},
"jest": {
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^/opt/nodejs/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/layers/common/$1"
    }
  }
...
```

Comment: It cannot be done in Mocha?